# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' in a scrapy

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I was doing a scrapy with python3.5 then this happened:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "F:/PyCharm/xiaozhou/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl nvospider".split())

File "F:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 108, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()

File "F:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 60, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')

File "F:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 285, in setmodule
    self.set(key, getattr(module, key), priority)

File "F:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 260, in set
    self.attributes[name].set(value, priority)

File "F:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 55, in set
    value = BaseSettings(value, priority=priority)

File "F:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.update(values, priority)

File "F:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 317, in update
    for name, value in six.iteritems(values): 

File "F:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 581, in iteritems
    return iter(d.items(**kw))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Following is my code:
This is spider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from xiaozhou.items import NovelspiderItem

class novSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "nvospider"
    redis_key = 'nvospider:start_urls'
    start_urls = ['http://www.daomubiji.com/']

def parse(self,response):
    selector = Selector(response)
    table = selector.xpath('//table')
    for each in table:
        bookname = each.xpath('tr/td[@colspam="3"]/center/h2/text()').extract()[0]
        content = each.xpath('tr/td/a/text()').extract()
        url = each.xpath('tr/td/a/@herf').extract()

        for i in range(len(url)):
            item = NovelspiderItem()
            item['bookname'] = bookname
            item['chapterURL'] = url[i]
            try:
                item['bookTitle'] = content[i].split(' ')[0]
                item['chapterNum'] = content[i].split(' ')[1]
            except Exception.e:
                 continue
            try:
                item['chapterName'] = content[i].split(' ')[2]
            except Exception.e:
                item['chapterName'] = content[i].split(' ')[1][-3:]
            yield item
```

Pipelines:

```
class XiaozhouPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_HOST'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT']
        )
        db = connection[settings['MONGO_DBNAME']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]
    def process_item(self,item,spider):
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        return item
```

items:
    from scrapy import Field, Item

```
class NovelspiderItem(Item):
    bookName = Field()
    bookTitle = Field()
    chapterNum = Field()
    chapterName = Field()
    chapterURL = Field()
```

settings:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
BOT_NAME = 'xiaozhou'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['xiaozhou.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'xiaozhou.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = ['xiaozhou.pipelines.XiaozhouPipeline']
USER_AGENT = ''
COOKIES_ENABLED = True
MONGODB_SERVER = "localhost"
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
MONGODB_DB = "dbxiaozhou"
MONGODB_COLLECTION = "xiaozhou"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the docs `ITEM_PIPELINES` setting [should be dict](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#item-pipelines), and you got list instead `ITEM_PIPELINES = ['xiaozhou.pipelines.XiaozhouPipeline']`

Comment: Worked for me. Changed from list to dict like this: {'stack.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline': 0}, the zero is the execution priority according to documentation